# Teammates not seeing "Checkout" but "Checkout as"

Tags: git, intellij-idea

I have put up a new project for my teammates, and it seems like that I am the only one who can do a proper checkout without using the terminal.

But my other teammates have to go to the terminal and write `git checkout feature/login` for example. They keep getting the option to `checkout as` and create a new branch from it.

How can I fix it for them?

[image: Checkout]

This is what I have, but they are getting `Checkout as` constantly.
Is it because I created those branches?

Comment: can you explain where you're seeing this or where your screenshot is from? And some further details on the setup?
You've tagged this github _and_ gitlab, but it can't be both if you're using a UI

Answer (score 0):

Your menu comes from the recent IntelliJ IDEA 2019.3.1

[image: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/user_images/sw6lo2uXdimD8for2Q8wxg.png]

Check first if your colleague have an older version, where it was easy to right-click a origin branch and check out local branch which is automatically tracked to its origin pair.

See [issue IDEA-197078](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-197078) for the `checkout as` option.